# Is it possible to order by a composite key with JPA and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to create a query using the JPA CriteriaBuilder and I would like to add an `ORDER BY` clause. This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "brands")
public class Brand implements Serializable {

    public enum OwnModeType {
        OWNER, LICENCED
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private IdBrand id;
    private String code;
    //bunch of other properties
}
```

Embedded class is:

```
@Embeddable
public class IdBrand implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Edition edition;
    private String name;
}
```

And the way I am building my query is like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Brand> q = cb.createQuery(Brand.class).distinct(true);
Root<Brand> root = q.from(Brand.class);
if (f != null) {
    f.addCriteria(cb, q, root);
    f.addOrder(cb, q, root, sortCol, ascending);
}
return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

And here are the functions called:

```
public void addCriteria(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<?> q, Root<Brand> r) {
}

public void addOrder(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<?> q, Root<Brand> r, String sortCol, boolean ascending) {
    if (ascending) {
        q.orderBy(cb.asc(r.get(sortCol)));
    } else {
        q.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get(sortCol)));
    }
}
```

If I try to set `sortCol` to something like `"id.name"` I get the following error:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [id.name] against path

Any idea how I could accomplish that? I tried searching online, but I couldn't find a hint about this... Also would be great if I could do a similar `ORDER BY` when I have a `@ManyToOne` relationship (for instance, `"id.edition.number"`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem is** your understanding of JPA path usage. [JPA Manual](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa) says:

> Path expression whose type is a persistable user class can be extended
>   further by reusing the dot (.) operator. For example, c.capital.name
>   is a nested path expression that continues from the Capital entity
>   object to its name field. **A path expression can be extended further
>   only if its type is also a user defined persistable class.** The dot (.)
>   operator cannot be applied to collections, maps and values of simple
>   types (number, boolean, string, date).

In your case you used id.edition.number, where **IdBrand (id) is not user persistable class.**

**To solution is** building path expression this way: `root.get("id").get("edition.number");`

---

To avoid such problems, you can write a path builder, which based on `javax.persistence.metamodel.Attribute.PersistentAttributeType` would decide the way path is built. For basic elements - use .get(), for collection elements use .join().

For you to understand your error, you need to read more information on JPA paths in general. [Here is a good manual on JPA paths](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path#Navigation_through_Path_Expressions_).

Comment: Yes that is what it says in the other answer I linked to.
I find this really annoying and don't understand why it couldn't work automagically. To your knowledge, would I have the same issue if I used IdClass instead of EmbeddedId?

Comment: Well, if we look at [JPA Type Hierarchy](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/metamodel#Type_Interface_Hierarchy_), we can see, that EntityType extends IdentifiableType, so maybe @Id (@IdClass) is identifiable type, so you can do that. You should try it out. Also get PersistentType from attribute, then you can define what you can do with it.

Comment: As I am saying, **maybe** it is possible, so you better check out the PersistentType, and provide it here if you can Please.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer on another similar issue: [JPA - Criteria API and EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid)

Here is how I fixed my code:

```
public void addOrder(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<?> q, Root<Brand> r, String sortCol, boolean ascending) {
    Path<?> p = r;
    String []sortCols = sortCol.split("\\."); // This is a regexp, hence the escape backslash
    for(String sc: sortCols) {
        p = p.get(sc);
    }
    if (ascending) {
        q.orderBy(cb.asc(p));
    } else {
        q.orderBy(cb.desc(p));
    }
}
```