# Use criteria to query embeddable object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria, toplink, embeddable

I'm using Toplink Grid(Eclipselink) as the my JPA implementation framework.

I met a a exception as below while I tried to use Criteria to query a Embeddable object:

```
 Exception [EclipseLink-6119] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The join expression 
Query Key conInfo
   Base domain.de1003.Employee is not valid, or for a mapping type that does not support joining.
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Employee )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.mappingForExpressionDoesNotSupportJoining(QueryException.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.JoinedAttributeManager.prepareJoinExpression(JoinedAttributeManager.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.JoinedAttributeManager.prepareJoinExpressions(JoinedAttributeManager.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ReportItem.initialize(ReportItem.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1038)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2917)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1273)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:714)
```

And the code I tried are as below:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ContactInfo> cq = cb.createQuery(ContactInfo.class);
Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);
cq.select(root.<ContactInfo> get("conInfo"));
cq.where(cb.le(root.<Long> get("employId"), 3));

TypedQuery<ContactInfo> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<ContactInfo> results = q.getResultList();
```

In Which ContactInfo is an embeddable class consisting of an address and set of phones. Phone is String filed.

Any help will be very appreciated.

I check the question related to this issue:
[JPA - Criteria API and EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid)

But it didn't solve my question.

And I can't find any example code.

TO James:

The entity code as below:

```
    package domain.de1003;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import oracle.eclipselink.coherence.integrated.config.GridCacheCustomizer;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Customizer;

import com.tangosol.io.pof.PofReader;
import com.tangosol.io.pof.PofWriter;
import com.tangosol.io.pof.PortableObject;

@Entity(name="Employee")
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@Customizer(oracle.eclipselink.coherence.integrated.config.GridCacheCustomizer.class)
public class Employee implements PortableObject,Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "EM_ID")
private long employId;

@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LASTNAME")
private String lastName;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="homePhone", column=@Column(name="HOMEPHONE")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="workPhone", column=@Column(name="WORKPHONE"))
})
private ContactInfo conInfo;

@Version
private long version;

public long getEmployId() {
    return employId;
}

public void setEmployId(long employId) {
    this.employId = employId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public ContactInfo getConInfo() {
    return conInfo;
}

public void setConInfo(ContactInfo conInfo) {
    this.conInfo = conInfo;
}

public long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Override
public void readExternal(PofReader pofReader) throws IOException {
    employId = pofReader.readLong(1);
    firstName = pofReader.readString(2);
    lastName = pofReader.readString(3);
    version = pofReader.readLong(4);

}

@Override
public void writeExternal(PofWriter pofWriter) throws IOException {
    pofWriter.writeLong(1, employId);
    if(firstName != null) pofWriter.writeString(2, firstName);
    if(lastName != null) pofWriter.writeString(3,lastName);
    pofWriter.writeLong(4, version);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" 
    + "employId = " + employId
    + " firstName = " + firstName
    + " lastName = " + lastName
    + " contact inforamtion: " + conInfo
    + "]";
}
```

}

and Entity ContactInfo

```
    package domain.de1003;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import oracle.eclipselink.coherence.integrated.config.GridCacheCustomizer;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Customizer;

import com.tangosol.io.pof.PofReader;
import com.tangosol.io.pof.PofWriter;
import com.tangosol.io.pof.PortableObject;

@Embeddable
@Customizer(oracle.eclipselink.coherence.integrated.config.GridCacheCustomizer.class)
public class ContactInfo implements PortableObject,Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;

@Column(name = "HOMEPHONE")
private String homePhone;

@Column(name = "WORKPHONE")
private String workPhone;

@Column(name = "CELLPHONE")
private String cellPhone;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getHomePhone() {
    return homePhone;
}

public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
    this.homePhone = homePhone;
}

public String getWorkPhone() {
    return workPhone;
}

public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) {
    this.workPhone = workPhone;
}

public String getCellPhone() {
    return cellPhone;
}

public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
}

@Override
public void readExternal(PofReader pofReader) throws IOException {
    address = pofReader.readString(1);
    homePhone = pofReader.readString(2);
    workPhone = pofReader.readString(3);
    cellPhone = pofReader.readString(4);
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(PofWriter pofWriter) throws IOException {
    if(address != null) pofWriter.writeString(1, address);
    if(homePhone != null) pofWriter.writeString(2, homePhone);
    if(workPhone != null) pofWriter.writeString(3, workPhone);
    if(cellPhone != null) pofWriter.writeString(4, cellPhone);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" 
    + "address = " + address
    + " homePhone = " + homePhone
    + " workPhone = " + workPhone
    + " cellPhone = " + cellPhone
    + "]";
}
```

}

For the equivalent JQPL

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e.conInfo FROM Employee e where e.employId < 3");

worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reproducing this in the latest EclipseLink (a 2.5 nightly) but couldn't.  I suspect it might be fixed with criteria API changes to add On support - can you give it a shot to confirm it?  You might have to turn off the cache to use the latest version of EclipseLink to test with though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just download the 2.5 night build and it works,the exception is gone. I will track the code change on that. We are still applying EclpseLink2.1.2 on our product. And I only tested with the latest release v2.4.1 which still pop up the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check if conInfo is the correct name of your attribute (include your entity code).

Does the equivalent JPQL work?

Comment: From the error it sounds like you are using "join" not "get", ensure you have compiled/deployed your code correctly.  Otherwise it could be a bug, check if you are on the latest release, and log a bug.