# Play 2.0 creating a finder when using a composite (embeded) key: not working correctly

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a model called Totals

```
@Entity
public class Totals extends Model{
@EmbeddedId
private TotalsPK id;
public Totals(TotalsPK key, Integer _count)
{
    id = key;
    count = _count;
}

public static Finder<TotalsPK,Totals> find = new Finder<TotalsPK, Totals> (
        TotalsPK.class, Totals.class
);

public static Totals find(TotalsPK id) 
 {
    //try this way instead of relying on find.byId working..... same error though!
    return find.where().eq("user_id", id.getUserId()).eq("item_id", id.getItemId()).findUnique();
//  return find.byId(id);
 }
........... etc
```

And then I have my key class

```
@Embeddable
public class TotalsPK {

private Long userId;
private Long itemId;

public TotalsPK(Long _userId, Long _itemId)
{
    userId = _userId;
    itemId = _itemId;
}

public boolean equals(Object rhs)
{
    return (userId.equals(((TotalsPK)rhs).getUserId()) && itemId.equals(((TotalsPK)rhs).getItemId()));
}

public int hashCode()
{
    //from Effective Java Chapter 3
    int result = (int) (userId ^ (userId >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (int) (itemId ^ (itemId >>> 32));
    return result;  
}
```

This works fine when searching for a record which doesnt exist, but when searching for one that does exist the object passed to "equals" from Ebean is null and I have no idea why this is, any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Null checking the rhs value passed into equals stops it crashing, but the equals check is never hit

thanks

Comment: You should use equals for Long comparison: `(userId.equals(((TotalsPK)rhs).getUserId()) && itemId.equals(((TotalsPK)rhs).getItemId()))` in your primary key class.

Comment: ah yes of course, thank you (would have worked in c++!!). my problem still persists though with that fixed!

Comment: just for the sake of completeness what is the source code of `Model`?

Comment: It isnt my code so not sure if pasting it here would do much good. but plays API page for it is here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/db/ebean/Model.html

Comment: also you should use `@Override` annotation on equals/hashCode(). Equals method should first check for nulls anyway and do type check, as it was shown in Effective Java.

Comment: also why your field id/userId(?) is queried as user_id? maybe this link is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid

Comment: @Stowelly, ah I see that it's playframework class.

Comment: will add the override annotation, i mentioned the null check in my post, it stops it crashing but the == is never hit. and "user_id" is what play / ebean generates based on my variable userId

Comment: is it working with finder `.byId()`?

Comment: tbh  `"id"` or `"id.userId"` would look better, what a strange framework :-)

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace (with the NullPointerException)?

Comment: the result is identical when using .byId(). here is the stack trace: TotalsPK.equals(Object) line: 33 
      CQuery<T>.setLoadedBean(Object, Object) line: 483 
SqlTreeNodeRoot.postLoad(DbReadContext, Object, Object) line: 34 
SqlTreeNodeRoot(SqlTreeNodeBean).load(DbReadContext, Object, int) line: 365 
CQuery<T>.readRow() line: 560 
CQuery<T>.readBeanInternal(boolean) line: 594 
CQuery<T>.readBean() line: 572 
CQueryEngine.find(OrmQueryRequest<T>) line: 277 
DefaultOrmQueryEngine.findId(OrmQueryRequest<T>) line: 154 
OrmQueryRequest<T>.findId() line: 310

Comment: DefaultServer.findId(Query<T>, Transaction) line: 1214 
DefaultServer.find(Class<T>, Object, Transaction) line: 1118 
DefaultServer.find(Class<T>, Object) line: 1105 
Model$Finder<I,T>.byId(I) line: 237 
Totals.find(TotalsPK) line: 82