# criteria query with Endeded object

Tags: hibernate

Below is my Pojos

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XXXXXXXX")
public class MyDTO1 implements Serializable{

@Embeded
private MyDTO2 myDTO2;
private Integer int1;
}

@Embedable
public class MyDTO2 implements Serializable{

private String string1;
}
```

Actual Class:

```
pulic class Test(){

private void testMethod(){
Session session = getSession();
List<ClientProgramINDTO> clientProgramDto = session.createCriteria(ClientProgramINDTO.Class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("int1", 1))
.add(Restrictions.eq("myDTO2.string1", "Test")).list();
}


}
```

I am getting below error message:

```
could not resolve property myDTO2.string1  in MyDto1.
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate you are using

Comment: What is your `ClientProgramINDTO` pojo looks like and how is it related to other pojo's

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to use `metamodel`.

I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid) solves your problem. Have a look and detailed explanantion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the your code:

`@Embeded` should be `@Embedded` in entity `MyDTO1`

`@Embedable` should be `@Embeddable` in entity `MyDTO2`

`pulic class Test(){` should be `public class Test{`

`ClientProgramINDTO.Class` should be `ClientProgramINDTO.class`

So without fixing these compilation issues you cannot run the program.

Also, you have not provided what `ClientProgramINDTO` object is and how is it related to other entities, I am assuming that `ClientProgramINDTO` is same as `MyDTO1`.

If I proceed based on my assumption then there is no issue in the code. Here is the sample code that I have tried:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        saveData();
        testMethod();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
    private static void saveData() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        ClientProgramINDTO c = new ClientProgramINDTO();
        c.setInt1(1);
        c.setMyDTO2(new MyDTO2("Test"));
        session.save(c);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    private static void testMethod() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        List<ClientProgramINDTO> clientProgramDto = session
                .createCriteria(ClientProgramINDTO.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("int1", 1))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("myDTO2.string1", "Test")).list();
        for (ClientProgramINDTO clientProgramINDTO : clientProgramDto) {
            System.out.println(clientProgramINDTO.getInt1() + " "+ clientProgramINDTO.getMyDTO2().getString1());

        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
    }
}
```

**Output of this program:**

1 Test