# JPA criteria query sorting and filtering on embedded key

Tags: sorting, jpa, criteria-api

**EDIT: Answered by Pascal Thivent in post [JPA - Criteria API and EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid)**

Background: I'm using a PrimeFaces 5 datatable with lazy loading and column sorting/filtering to display a set of data retrieved from a MySQL database.

Problem: The data set is pulled from a target entity that includes an embedded key from a parent entity, which itself includes an embedded key from its parent entity (see code sample below).  How can I sort/filter the target entity based on a value from its own embedded key?

```
    //
    // Top-level entity
    //
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "top_level")
    @XmlRootElement
    public class TopLevel implements Serializable
    {
        @Id
      @Column(name = "top_level_id")
        private Integer topLevelId;

        ...
    }

    //
    // Primary key of second-level entity
    //
    @Embeddable
    public class SecondLevelPK implements Serializable
    {
      @Column(name = "top_level_id")
        private int topLevelId;

      @Column(name = "second_level_name")
        private String secondLevelName;

        ...
    }

    //
    // Second-level entity
    //
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "second_level")
    @XmlRootElement
    public class SecondLevel implements Serializable
    {
        @EmbeddedId
        protected SecondLevelPK secondLevelPK;

      @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        ...
    }

    //
    // Primary key of target entity
    //
    @Embeddable
    public class TargetEntityPK implements Serializable
    {
      @Column(name = "top_level_id")
        private int topLevelId;

      @Column(name = "second_level_name")
        private String secondLevelName;

      @Column(name = "target_entity_code")
        private String targetCode;

        ...
    }

    //
    // Target entity
    //
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "target_entity")
    @XmlRootElement
    public class TargetEntity implements Serializable
    {
        @EmbeddedId
        protected TargetEntityPK targetEntityPK;

      @Column(name = "target_entity_title")
        private String targetEntityTitle;

        ...
    }
```

This is the criteria query that successfully loads all records, including the embedded key fields:-

```
    CriteriaQuery cq = getCriteriaQuery();
    Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);  // entityClass type is TargetEntity

    cq.select(rt);

    Query q = getQuery(cq);

    q.getResultList();
```

I can sort on fields that aren't part of the embedded key as follows:-

```
    cq.orderBy(getCriteriaBuilder().asc(rt.get(sortField)));
```

How should I modify the general query or the orderBy clause to be able to sort on `TargetEntityPK.targetCode`?

Similarly I need to be able to filter on the same field, but I suspect the answer to sorting will also solve the filtering problem.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084431/jpa-criteria-api-and-embeddedid help?

Comment: Hi Leo - I've just found that post and the answer by @Pascal Thivent is the solution that I was looking for.  Thank you.